# Convert image from url to Base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using an Image File, I am getting the url of an image, that needs be to send to a webservice. From there the image has to be saved locally on my system.

The code I am using:

```
var imagepath = $("#imageid").val();// from this getting the path of the selected image

that var st = imagepath.replace(data:image/png or jpg; base64"/"");
```

How to convert the image url to BASE64?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: If you're just trying to encode the url and not the image data, you might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**HTML**

```html
<img id="imageid" src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/?[A-z]*;base64,/);
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageid"));
```

Special thanks to [@Md. Hasan Mahmud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-from-url-to-base64/22172860?noredirect=1#comment131922661_22172860) for providing an improved regex that works with any image mime type in my comments!

This method requires the canvas element, which is [perfectly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

- The MDN reference of [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).
- And the official [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl).

Comment: This does not work when you create and add the `<img>` in JS, I believe. Because I got `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`.

Comment: @Rubinous - Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror). I don't think your problem/exception has something to do with my code. Otherwise, feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: This is the correct answer to OP's question. For my sake, I wanted to use the actual results of `toDataURL` in a CSS `background-image`. So, I **do need** all the preceding `data:image/png;base64,` stuff, so I just returned dataURL's value directly (I didn't need the RegEx replace). Thanks!

Comment: The conversion part 
`var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");`
works great on Angular too.

Comment: You need to use img.naturalWidth and img.naturalHeight to handle scaled-down images

Comment: i like to use `return dataURL.split(',')[1];` instead of your version, and yep! height and width were needed i found out the hard way :p

Comment: I have src="/something.svg" like this how do i convert this.

Comment: The best conversion would be:
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/?[A-z]*;base64,/);

work for any type of image extension(png,jpeg,jpg etc)

Answer (score 84):

View this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/5065874 by @HaNdTriX

Basically, he implemented this function:

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

And in your case, you can use it like this:

```
toDataUrl(imagepath, function(myBase64) {
    console.log(myBase64); // myBase64 is the base64 string
});
```

Comment: blob is a horrible way to handle your images as it use "screenshot" to make the image. This mean that the image get difference size depends on the users screen resolution

Comment: in my case with typescript it is console.log(myBase64);  is showing undefined

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor how do you suggest solving the problem without a blob? thanks!

Comment: Some time it throughs CROS origin request Error to make a call using HttpRequest for receive image from URL

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor blob size depends on screen resolution? What!?

Comment: @Jerther if it uses "screenshot" browser feature, it's not a leap to assume it depends on the resolution of the user's screen.

Answer (score 66):

In todays JavaScript, this will work as well..

```js
const imageUrlToBase64 = async (url) => {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await data.blob();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      resolve(base64data);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
};

imageUrlToBase64('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i7cTyGnCwLIJhT1t2YpLW-zHt8ZKalgQiqfrYnZQl975-ygD_0mOXaYZMzekfKW_ydHRutDbNzeqpWoLkFR4Yx2Z2bgNj2XskKJrfw8').then(console.log)
```

Comment: How would you do this with a specific image mimetype?

Comment: Never tried but I think `blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png"` will work

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: This one work in more cases than solutions using `canvas.toDataURL(...)`

Answer (score 2):

This is your html-

```
    <img id="imageid" src="">
    <canvas id="imgCanvas" />
```

Javascript should be-

```
   var can = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
   var img = document.getElementById("imageid");
   var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
   var encodedBase = can.toDataURL();
```

'encodedBase' Contains Base64 Encoding of Image.

Answer (score 2):

I try using the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22172860/8872638), but it occur `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported`.

I found this is because of [cross domain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported), the solution is

```
function convert(oldImag, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        callback(img)
    }
    img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = oldImag.src;
}
function getBase64Image(img,callback) {
    convert(img, function(newImg){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = newImg.width;
        canvas.height = newImg.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(newImg, 0, 0);
        var base64=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        callback(base64)
    })
}
getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageid"),function(base64){
// base64 in here.
    console.log(base64)
});
```

Comment: By this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image your code will not work without server side change ... adding header Access-Control-Allow-Origin for image. So if we wish to convert image from 3rd party domain your code will not work. In case facebook or google user image from OAuth2 login is this code working because of both return header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Used This :

```
function ViewImage(){
 function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
var file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file).then(data =>$("#ImageBase46").val(data));
}
```

Add To Your Input onchange=ViewImage();

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
<div id="imgTest"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
        alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        console.log("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This one is perfect. Here is also a **Working Fiddle** of the above code by me https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/ed9j7epr/

Comment: hello, how can this be applied on a remote url without facing cross domain issues?

Comment: how can we convert remote url to base64 with this ? Not correct solution

Answer (score 0):

```
let baseImage = new Image;
baseImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
baseImage.src = your image url

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = baseImage.width;
  canvas.height = baseImage.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Additional information about "CORS enabled images": [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)

Comment: be advice, you'ld wrap the conversion within an event handler connecting to the loaded event since the image might not be loaded when trying to convert; https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442874/1098814

Comment: I  get error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108669/typescript-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-todataurl-on-htmlcanvas?noredirect=1#comment95051919_54108669

Answer (score 0):

```
imageToBase64 = (URL) => {
    let image;
    image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        try {
            localStorage.setItem('saved-image-example', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    });
    image.src = URL;
};

imageToBase64('image URL')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to chime in and post how I did it. This is basically @Haialaluf's approach but a bit shorter:

```
const imageUrlToBase64 = async (url) => {
    const data = await fetch(url)
    const blob = await data.blob();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onload = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        return base64data
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This one uses `canvas.ToDataURL(...)`

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL;
}
```

This one works in more cases because it avoids canvas by re-fetching the `img.src`

```js
const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await data.blob();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;   
      resolve(base64data);
    }
  });
}
```

---

As a bonus, this one uses both functions before to read all images in the page and uses the first function if it works, otherwise it uses the second one, and returns a markdown image embedding of the image with its alt text as the title and the base64 as the source.

```js
const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
[...images].forEach(async img => {
  let base64;
  try {
    base64 = getBase64Image(img);      
  } catch (error) {
    base64 = await getBase64FromUrl(img.src);
  };
  const markdown = `![${img.alt}](${base64})`;
  console.log(markdown, img);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the Typescript version of Abubakar Ahmad's answer

```
function imageTo64(
  url: string, 
  callback: (path64: string | ArrayBuffer) => void
): void {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onload = (): void => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    reader.onloadend = (): void => callback(reader.result);
  }
}
```