# Spring Controller @RequestBody with file upload is it possible?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipart, multipartform-data

I have a Controller like this and I want to submit a form with file uploading as well as some form data like label as shown below. Also, I want to do that using @RequestBody so I can use the @Valid annotation on the wrapper as more variables will be added.

```
public @ResponseBody WebResponse<Boolean> updateEUSettings(
    final Locale locale,
    @Validated @ModelAttribute final EUPSettingsWrapper endUserPortalSettingsWrapper) {
}
```

And my wrapper is:

```
public class EUPSettingsWrapper {

    private String label;
    private MultipartFile logo;
// getter , setters..etc...
}
```

But I would like to convert it into a @RequestBody from ModelAttributes.

The way I'm trying is by having the file upload separated as request parameter like this:

```
public @ResponseBody WebResponse<Boolean> updateEUSettings(
    final Locale locale,
    @Validated @RequestBody final EUPSettingsWrapper endUserPortalSettingsWrapper, 
    @RequestParam(value = "file1", required = true) final MultipartFile logo) {

    endUserPortalSettingsWrapper.setLogo(logo);

    // ...
}
```

In my mock MVC, I am setting:

```
getMockMvc().perform(fileUpload(uri).file(logo)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(JSONUtils.toJSON(wrapper))
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

But I'm getting an error like this which says:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data' not supported
```

Does anyone have a good idea of how Multipart file uploads can be used with @RequestBody? Anything I am doing wrong above?

Comment: See this https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can actually simplify your life here since all you are doing is submitting a form that contains some fields and file.
You **don't** need @RequestBody for what you are trying to do. You can use regular Spring MVC features, so your controller method would look like:

```
@ResponseBody
public WebResponse<Boolean> updateEUSettings(
     Locale locale, 
     @Valid EUPSettingsWrapper endUserPortalSettingsWrapper, 
     @RequestParam(value = "file1", required = true) MultipartFile logo
) {


}
```

The client that submits the request to this controller will need to have a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

In your Spring MVC test you would write something like this:

```
getMockMvc().perform(fileUpload(uri).file("file1", "some-content".getBytes()) 
                        .param("someEuSettingsProperty", "someValue")
                        .param("someOtherEuSettingsProperty", "someOtherValue")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Very interesting, but how does the data looks in the Ajax POST request? Do you create a Object to represent EUPSettingsWrapper and a FormData to represent the MultipartFile and then you assign the FormData to, let's say, obj.logo ? Also do you JSON.stringify() that obj or not?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really remember since the answer is pretty old :)

Comment: Another way is encode your file bytes into base64 and then generated string can be use in request json, generally this patten is not recommended but for special schenarios:
{"name":"aa","logo":encodeBase64(fileByteArray)}
for encoding follow given url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64/22172860

Answer (score 13):

I couldn't find a way to use @RequestBody.

However, you can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadStuff", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyViewDto doStuff(@RequestPart("json") @Valid MyDto dto,
                         @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) { ... }
```

You can test it like this:

```
MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("json", "",
            "application/json", "{}".getBytes());
MockMultipartFile dataFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "foo.zip", "application/octet-stream", bytes);

mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/uploadStuff")
            .file(dataFile)
            .file(jsonFile))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Answer (score 12):

Please add the following bean in your spring-servlet.xml to add the support for multipart  request.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Also don't forget to add the dependency for **commons-fileupload jar**

Comment: Also see this answer for how to set it up in a Java-based configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883166/3960852

Answer (score -1):

I struggled a little with this and ended up passing as simple parameters. Fine if you don't have lots to pass in your request:

```
myMethod(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile myFile,
        @RequestParam("param1") Float param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2 {}
```

Answer (score -2):

For Spring 4 and later you can do the following to get the full object:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@Payload EUPSettingsWrapper wrapper) {

}
```

Note: Also should work without the tag

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(EUPSettingsWrapper wrapper) {

}
```