# Ionic 2 - Need to convert image from an url to base64 string

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am getting file url from server through http.post request. I need to convert image to base64 string for database storage.

Please let me know how can i convert image from an url to base64 string in ionic 2

Comment: I suggest converting image to Base64 on server side in order to avoid unnecessary data processing on user's end.

Answer (score 2):

As Stefan managed you probably want to do this server side; however if for whatever reason you cannot there's a bajillion resources out there showing you how to convert an image to base64. It's nothing Ionic specific, you can with just some javascript action. The below should get you started.

[How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

[CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)