# Javascript Convert a URL to a base64 Image

Tags: javascript, base64

I am trying to convert an image url to a base64 image. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64) which I am trying to make use of.

I have the following code:

```
var imgUrl = 'https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png';
let base64image = this.getBase64Image(imgUrl);
console.log(base64image);
```

and

```
public getBase64Image(imgUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgUrl;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

But, it outputs the following:

> data:,

I get the following error in the console:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
>       Error: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

My code must me incoreect. Can anyone please advise how to convert the url to a base64 image?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I aded the following line to the function:

```
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

That got rid of the error, however, now I get the following:

> data:,

Comment: Look at the error messages you get on the console — *Error: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.*

Comment: Added the error message. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You marked this as a duplicate, which question does it duplicate?

Comment: The one mentioned in the big yellow box at the top of the question

Comment: Quentin, I resolved the error message by setting 'crossOrigin', 'anonymous', see UPDATE above. Thank you. However, it still does not resolve my issue that I am trying to create a base64Image.

Comment: Please can you unmark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XHR and the File Reader API instead, which is cleaner but is limited in [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility).

```
var imgxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    imgxhr.open( "GET", url );
    imgxhr.responseType = "blob";
    imgxhr.onload = function (){
        if ( imgxhr.status===200 ){
            reader.readAsDataURL(imgxhr.response);
        }
        else if ( imgxhr.status===404 ){
            // Error handle
        }
    };
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log(reader.result.length);
        // Code here
    };
imgxhr.send();
```

Comment: I am building an Ionic mobile app. Will it work in that environment?

Comment: Does that mean it will not work in IE10 and Safari 6?

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with that framework.

Comment: @Richard According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility) it will work in IE 10 and Safari 6

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway, I think I need to look for another solution then. Hopefully your solution can help someone else.