# How to convert a image url into base64 image source usign javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi please suggest me a code for converting a image url into base64 image source

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 0):

check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22172860/7979057
seems that it's you want. maybe will need change some part of function only

Comment: thanks for response but it's not resolve  my problem however when i run example code it's gives only data; as output