# Convert image to base64 without server

Tags: javascript, base64, pinterest

I'm using the Pinterest Javascript SDK to try and create a pin. The parameters to set the image is 1 of either;

`image` - Upload the image you want to pin using multipart form data

`image_url` - The link to the image that you want to Pin, or

`image_base64` - The link of a Base64 encoded image

I'm trying to create the Pin from the client side, without going through a server. My form is simply:

```
<div class="file-upload">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
```

and I read the value of that using

```
const imageUrl = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;
```

I have tried both the `image` and `image_url` parameters to send that value (`imageUrl`) through, but because the value resolves to a place on my hard drive, it doesn't work (probably expectantly).

So now I have to try and figure out how to use the `image_base64` option, which means I need to convert the image to base64 on the users machine.

How could I go about doing that? Or better yet, if someone knows how I can use the `image` parameter, I think that would be much better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `change` event attached to `<input type="file">` element,  `FileReader` to convert `File` object at `<input type="file">` element `.files` property to a `data URI` or `base64` portion of `data URI` within `change` event handler

```html
<div class="file-upload">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
<script>
  const input = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
  const reader = new FileReader;
  reader.onload = () => {
    const dataURL = reader.result;
    const base64 = reader.result.split(",").pop();
    console.log(dataURL, base64);
  }
  input.onchange = () => {
    reader.abort();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
</script>
```