# Base64 image not opening up when converted from Image URL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, base64

I am converting an image to Base64 from Image URL using canvas. The approach I am taking is similar to below 2 links but the converted Base64 string is not opening up the image when viewed in Chrome Tab.

**Links**

[CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)
(1st answer with 81 thumbs up).

https://jsfiddle.net/3qshvc54/

I tried consoling the img, canvas, ctx in fiddle and my code. The console output is the same. Please see below screenshots.
If I do it by fiddle the converted Base64 URL opens up fine in a new tab, but the one generated from my code does not display an image when opened up in a new tab.

*I am using same Image URL in my code and Fiddle*

**Console screenshot when running from my code**

[image]

**Console screenshot when running from Fiddle**

[image]

**The Base64 generated from my code:**

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEQAAABDCAYAAAAlFqMKAAAApklEQVR4Xu3VsQ0AIAwEMbL/0tShQLrejHB6kzneKjB67AKCPIsQRJD/J2EhFmIh6ZAigwwyyKQCyCCTBuPKIIMMMqkAMsikwbgyyCCDTCqADDJpMK4MMsggkwogg0wajCuDDDLIpALIIJMG48oggwwyqQAyyKTBuDLIIINMKoAMMmkwrgwyyCCTCiCDTBqMK4MMMsikAsggkwbjyiCDDDKpADL/XBfFQABED54eAwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

**I tried validating the same online it shows that the Base64 string is valid:**

[image]

**When I try to decode the same:**

*It seems that the result of decoding is a binary data (MIME type detected as “image/png”) and because of this the data from “Text” may be damaged during the output.*

[image]

**My code:**

```
<div className='image-root'>
    <img id={`imageBlock-${props.photoBoxID}`} className="multi-image-photo" src={props.imgUrl} alt="photo"></img>
</div>

getBase64Image = (img) => {
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    console.log('img', img);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    console.log('canvas', canvas);
    console.log('ctx', ctx);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log('dataURL', dataURL);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.props.isUploaded && (prevProps.isUploaded !== this.props.isUploaded)){
        let imageRef = document.getElementById(`imageBlock-${this.props.photoBoxID}`);
        imageRef.onload = this.getBase64Image(imageRef);
    }    
}
```

Can you suggest why the Base64 string generated is not opening up fine if converted from my code, though it opens up from Fiddle? Is it corrupted?

Comment: When I copy the Data-uri to the address-bar, I get a 68x67px transparent image. and testing your fiddle, it's full of CORS-messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is an event you need function there and in that function you need to update `src`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.props.isUploaded && (prevProps.isUploaded !== this.props.isUploaded)){
        let imageRef = document.getElementById(`imageBlock-${this.props.photoBoxID}`);
        imageRef.onload = () => {
           delete imageRef.onload;
           imageRef.src = this.getBase64Image(imageRef);
        };
    }    
}
```

but better is to add base64 image to state and don't use getElementById directly in React applications.

**EDIT**:

for infinite loop I would create 2 images, if you need to render image on canvas you usually render outside of DOM:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.props.isUploaded && (prevProps.isUploaded !== this.props.isUploaded)){
        let imageRef = document.getElementById(`imageBlock-${this.props.photoBoxID}`);
        var srcImg = new Image();
        srcImg.onload = () => {
           imageRef.src = this.getBase64Image(srcImg);
        };
        srcImg.src = prevProps.imgUrl;
    }    
}
```

and remove the props from JSX template you will not need it.

And side note: if you have big image it's better to create object URL from blob, because there is limit of data that can be put into URL (for smaller images it should not matter):

```
function asObjectUrl(canvas) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        });
    });
}
```

The object url need to be removed when not needed to not create memory leaks (use [URL.revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL))

Comment: And here you go for a crazy fun infinite loop eating all the memory!

Comment: @Kaiido fixed the problem.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks. Now I am getting the thumbnail which is opening fine in a new tab, but it is still an infinite loop over onload. I can't use refs as I am working on react15 so have to use getElementByID approach.

Comment: @ShantanuTomar you can use two images one outside of DOM to get the source image and one as destination.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks. I will check that. On your second point, can you please let me know If my image size is ranging from 10KB to 10MB do I need to use blob? What is your parameter for 'big image'

Comment: @ShantanuTomar its depend of length of base64 and depend on browser. Se SO question: [Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695167/387194)

Comment: @jcubic Can you please check the EDIT 1 in question. I have edited my question.

Comment: @ShantanuTomar please don't edit your question with different question in SO there should be one specific question and one specific answer to the question. You said it working but now you have different question, please ask another one with different description, so it will be useful if someone search for similar thing.

Comment: @jcubic Corrected

Answer (score 0):

change your `img`'s `src` attribute adding `src="data:image/jpeg;base64` tag with the encoded string like below:

```
 <img id={`imageBlock-${props.photoBoxID}`} className="multi-image-photo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ${props.imgUrl}" alt="photo"></img>
```

This should work. 
**N.B.:** Please check your `imageString` variable carefully, I might have used the wrong one, not sure.