# How to make a base64 array from an array of photos

Tags: javascript, html, base64

```
const arrUrl = [
'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/getzen_doc/1714479/pub_5e4b9183baec8f365f1ff215_5e4b91c9bb4a6d368b8d9d4c/scale_1200',
'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/getzen_doc/1714479/pub_5e4b9183baec8f365f1ff215_5e4b91c9bb4a6d368b8d9d4c/scale_1200',
'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/getzen_doc/1714479/pub_5e4b9183baec8f365f1ff215_5e4b91c9bb4a6d368b8d9d4c/scale_1200',
'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/getzen_doc/1714479/pub_5e4b9183baec8f365f1ff215_5e4b91c9bb4a6d368b8d9d4c/scale_1200'
];
```

there is an array of different links to photos, how to make them all in base64, I have a script that makes base64 photos, but I can't combine them

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

// The magic begins after the image is successfully loaded
img.onload = function () {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
  canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Unfortunately, we cannot keep the original image type, so all images will be converted to PNG
  // For this reason, we cannot get the original Base64 string
  var uri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
    b64 = uri.replace(/^data:image.+;base64,/, '');

  console.log(b64); //-> "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWP4z8DwHwAFAAH/q842iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
};

// If you are loading images from a remote server, be sure to configure “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”
// For example, the following image can be loaded from anywhere.
var url = '//static.base64.guru/uploads/images/1x1.gif';
img.src = url;
```

**or**

https://gist.github.com/CawaKharkov/1c477d44fcfdf67aea3f/revisions#diff-7b3e9484330c338cea137079906c2390c4961003e07e3a9d13bed49d9d63805eR17

Comment: The link  of image is broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)

Comment: try to use join to combine then, but to use, you will need to split it again. img.join("||"); I think u cannot "merge" the images by code