# Get Base64 image data from image loaded on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, firefox-addon

Is it possible in Javascript/JQuery to get the base64 image data from an image on the page?

For example is there a function like...

```
<img id="foo" src="https://mywebsite.com/bar.png">

<script>
   var base64Data = $('#foo').base64();
</script>
```

Comment: no there isn't one that simple - I think you'll need to use a canvas

Comment: of course, since the image comes from your own server, why not do the base64 encoding there - to be honest, why do you need the base64 encoding anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)