# How to check if all the images are downloaded using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple animation of images in my application. There are multiple images in the document. I want that when the page loads the images should start to animate. I tried with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".slide").animate({
    left:'250px',
    opacity:'0.3',
  });

});
```

On my local server I get the desired effect since all the images are loaded instantly but when I run the same code on hosted server I do not get the desired effect. The image that loads first in sequence starts to animate while others animate as they loaded.

I want to all images to animate in parallel rather than serially. Can anyone tell me how do I ensure that images are loaded so that I can then animate all of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript/jQuery event listener on image load for all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442821/javascript-jquery-event-listener-on-image-load-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `$(document).ready()` function to `$(window).load` function as:

```
$(window).load(function() {

     $(".slide").animate({
        left:'250px',
        opacity:'0.3',
      });
});
```

The reason behind doing so is that `ready` event is fired when DOM elements are ready to be manipulated irrespective whether content inside them such as images, videos etc are downloaded or not where `load` event is fired when all the content has been downloaded as well in DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

If all your images are in the HTML of the document (none created dynamically), then you can simply switch to use `$(window).load()` which will not fire until all images in the page have finished loading:

```
$(window).load(function(){

 $(".slide").animate({
    left:'250px',
    opacity:'0.3',
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, the `dom ready` status means all the essential stuff is loaded and the page is ready to be interacted with.  Images continue to load in the background.

What you need is the `window.onload` event:

```
$( window ).load(function() {

 $(".slide").animate({
    left:'250px',
    opacity:'0.3',
  });

});
```