# jQuery on load event do not trigger script

Tags: jquery, css

First I was looking at the `onLoad` event, but then when I read about it, I discovered that I was or going to be deprecated, so I search and found this info to use the `on` event to check if an image is loaded:[load() method deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated)

But the simple animation I will trigger, will not work. The element is not visible. It works if I reload the browser. The animation worked perfect until I added the load event. What could be wrong and how can I improve the code to work better?

```
    $("#intro-img").on("load", function() {

    $(".intro-content").animate({
    left: '20px',
    opacity: '1.0'
    });

});
```

EDIT:
The script is running now after I used `window` instead of the id. Like this `$(window).on("load", function() {....` Now the script should run when all content on the page has been loaded? But I guess there is never a guarantee that it will work 100% with images!?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#book').on("load",function(){
  //animate
});
```

Problem with this approach is when image is loaded from cache load event has a possibility that it is never triggered.When image is first downloaded jquery can have a chance to attach the event before image is loaded and work expected.But if image is loaded so quickly via cache then jquery may not have.

```
$('#book').on("load",function(){
  $(".intro-content").animate({
    left: '20px',
    opacity: '0.5',
    height:"300px"
    });
}).each(function(){
  if(this.complete) {
    $(this).trigger('load');
  }
});
```

This code attaches event and also checks whether image is already loaded and triggers the load event.

Answer (score 0):

With $(window).load you must to wait to load all resources in web to execute script. You can make an image load event cross-browser. See this:

[JavaScript/jQuery event listener on image load for all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442821/javascript-jquery-event-listener-on-image-load-for-all-browsers)

Instead of your code

```
 $('image').on('load')
```

You can use

```
 $('image').load()
```

Or attaching events with eventListener.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but the .load is depricated!

Comment: ... or attaching events with `addEventListener` && `attachEvent` (IE)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the alternative JQuery function [$(document).ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".intro-content").animate({
         left: '20px',
         opacity: '1.0'
     });
  });
```