# image width and height returned is ZERO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am all images from a folder using javascript. I followed instructions from this link.
[How to load all the images from one of my folder into my web page, using Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery)

But when i try to get the image length and geight it returns **0**
here is my code.

```
window.onload = function() { 
var dir = "images/";
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        //Lsit all png file names in the page
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http:///", "");
            $("#gall").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img><span>Picture description</span>"));
            this.length;
        });
                pgal.display(); 
    }
});

}
```

In **pgal.display()**, i am simply writing width and height to console.

Comment: you might have to wait until image finish loading

Comment: `this` refers to what ?

Comment: @manassorn How can I do that?

Comment: @sheldoncooper this link might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442821/javascript-jquery-event-listener-on-image-load-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

You're need something like this:

```
$("#gall").find('img').on('load', function(event) { console.log(event.target) });
```

Comment: I used this, and here is the output on console.
<img src="images/pic11.jpg" style="z-index: 993333; left: 562px; top: 101px; width: 0px; height: 0px;">

Comment: looks like something sets `style` property outside

Comment: Remove the width and height attributes and read offsetWidth and offsetHeight

Comment: Still the result is same.

Comment: then preload images with `new Image` method

Comment: Can you provide an example, kindly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901677/the-definitive-best-way-to-preload-images-using-javascript-jquery